# Word Of Warcraft - DK quest - Runed Soulblade destroyed

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am a newbie in the WOW world.
I've started a DK class, but I can't solve the second quest because of the Runed Soulblade.
In fact, I've destroy it.

Since it, I can't progress in my game. I've received my Runed Soulblade in my mail, but I can't open it because I can't go in any capital.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a way to solve the problem.

I've contacted the blizzard support to explain my problem. They've answered me under 24h and gave my character my lost/destroyed item :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can go down to the town there is at least one mailbox. And I guess if that doesn't work the quickest is just to start again.

Comment: The problem is that I can't go down to the town, cause I didn't finished yet all introduction quests. Also, I can't erase my character, because I have something in my mailbox.